# Junit test case for following json without giving direct values or hardcoding

Tags: java, junit

My json is

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": [
        { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
        { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
        { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
    ]
 }
```

So i wrote sample junit test case for method carinfo which is

```
@Test
public void Test(){
    assertEquals(carinfo.cars.get(0).name(), Temporary value);
}
```

I want a junit test case. so is it correct or any corrections

Comment: can we see the code behind this: ***carinfo.cars.get(0).name()***

Comment: I just used a sample json from internet

Comment: yes, but your json coming from internet must be converted into an object...

Comment: What is the purpose of this test?

Comment: to do junit testing @Compass

Comment: No, what are you testing?

Comment: i want to test method whether if the ids(like car name is null) are not null and remaining should be equal to other dummie values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your requirement is:

> I have a routine which deserialises the given JSON into `CarParts` and `Cars` and when I test that routine I don't want to hardcode my expectations instead I'd like to be able to interrogate the JSON programmatically to form assertions

For example:

```
@Test
public void testJson() {
    String json = "{\n"
        + "    \"name\":\"John\",\n"
        + "    \"age\":30,\n"
        + "    \"cars\": [\n"
        + "        { \"name\":\"Ford\", \"models\":[ \"Fiesta\", \"Focus\", \"Mustang\" ] },\n"
        + "        { \"name\":\"BMW\", \"models\":[ \"320\", \"X3\", \"X5\" ] },\n"
        + "        { \"name\":\"Fiat\", \"models\":[ \"500\", \"Panda\" ] }\n"
        + "    ]\n"
        + " }";

    CarInfo carinfo = deserialise(json);

    // for the above JSON this JsonPath call will return "Ford"
    Assert.assertEquals(JsonPath.read(json, "$.cars[0].name"), carinfo.getCars().get(0).getName());
}
```

If so, then [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) sounds like a good fit; it allows you to interrogate Json and to produce expectations for your test case like in the above example.

Comment: no this method is like hardcoding giving values directly but one fine day when the json values are changed then test case should be changed so i want without hardcoding